# Pdflatex: using a hand made style file gives surprising errors while with the commands in the root file there is none. What is wrong?

Tags: hyperref, undefined

I tried to analyse errors in a $^{+/-}$ construct which happended in my book: The minus were all shown as asteriks. Therefore I prepared a minimal example:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{scrbook}
%\usepackage{hormonbooktest}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{stix2}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\heterozyg}{$^{+/-}$}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\homozyg}{$^{+/+}$}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\minuszyg}{$^{-/-}$}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\gs}{$\rightwhitearrow$}
\begin{document}
    (\gs Shh\heterozyg) (\gs Shh\homozyg) (\gs Shh\minuszyg) 
\end{document}
```

This turned out to be correct. However, when I put the preamble in a style file I get errors: the command \gs is not found.

The style file is:

```
\ProvidesFile{hormonbooktest.sty}[2021/12/01 Bernhard Kleine]
\RequirePackage[ngerman]{babel}
\RequirePackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\RequirePackage[T1]{fontenc}
\RequirePackage{stix2}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\heterozyg}{$^{+/-}$}%heterozygous
\DeclareRobustCommand{\homozyg}{$^{+/+}$}%homozygouspositiv
\DeclareRobustCommand{\minuszyg}{$^{-/-}$}%homozygousnegativ
\DeclareRobustCommand*{\gs}[1]{\hyperlink{#1}{$\rightwhitearrow$#1}}%Verweise ins
%                                                                    Glossar
```

I would like to add that the original style file, much to large to be shown in a mwe, worked but for the asterisks, copying the style file into another file started the errors. Trimming the style file to the one above is still errorneous.

I am using texstudio (updated) and a fairly up-to-date texlive. If somebody could show me the errors in the style file I could go ahead with the analysis of wrong asteriks instead of minus signs.

Comment: the commands are not the same the error you get is `! Undefined control sequence.
\gs  #1->\hyperlink ` because you have not defined `\hyperlink` the version you have inline does not use that command

Comment: Note the error does not say that `\gs` is not defined, it says that `\hyperlink`, used in `\gs` is not defined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is unrelated to the use of a `.sty` file.

```
! Undefined control sequence.
\gs  #1->\hyperlink 
                    {#1}{$\rightwhitearrow $#1}
l.5     (\gs Shh\heterozyg) (\gs S
                                  hh\homozyg) (\gs Shh\minuszyg)
?
```

because `\hyperlink` is not defined (as `hyperref` has not been loaded).

The version of the file with the declarations inline does not use `\hyperlink` and does not generate this error.

Comment: The error was mine: hormonebooktest was not registered in the repository, and an older version in an oldversion subdirectory was used. Now the compilation works. I am going after the asteriks.